# Azure Function Blob Output Binding Metadata

Tags: python, azure-functions, blob

Is there a way to access the metadata of a blob output binding?

For example, my output binding path parameter is set to:

container/directory/{rand-guid}.txt

I would like to Set the path of the generated blob in the return value of the activity function.

I’m using Python as the worker.